# Visual Studio 2012 RC "psapi.dll" - Fatal Error On Startup

Tags: visual-studio-2010

After installing VS2012 RC on my dev PC, I keep getting this error on the splash screen on startup of the application, immediately after selecting the appropriate Environment Setting.

> Unable to load DLL 'psapi.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

VS2010 threw this error immediately after the VS2012 threw the error.  (VS2010 worked well prior to the 2012 Installation). **Both applications now don't even work at all.**

Things I've tried:

1. Tried running devenv with all the switch cmds of VS I know - /Resetsettings, /ResetSkipPkgs, /safemode
2. Uninstalling and installing ALL versions of VS on my PC (2008, 2010 and 2012) - after clearing the %temp% windows folder.
3. Formatted my PC and reinstalled all versions of VS again from the scratch.

**PLEASE NOTE : The Visual Studio 2012 worked when I restarted my windows in Safe Mode.**

My PC is a Lenovo i3, 4G RAM, 64Bit Windows 7.

Please help me as I have wasted days trying to solve this issue to no avail.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?  If so, I'd like to know what you did. Thanks.